# Do I have to use the entire UUID string to guarantee uniqueness?

Tags: python, unique, uuid

I'm using the UUID library in Python to generate unique ID's for object. More specifically, I'm basically doing

```
id_for_something = uuid.uuid4().hex
```

My question is, do I have to use the entire hexadecimal string value to guarantee that the ID's will be unique? Or is it okay to use, for example, the first 4 digits? I'm simply asking because using the entire string seems a bit long. Thanks!

Comment: What is the nb of element that will need an ID in the time ?

Comment: Nope, after at most (16**4) objects you will necessarily have repetitions. Which is of course not solved by using the entire string. The number is just bigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UUIDs are **never** guaranteed to be unique. For example if you generate 2.7 * 10^18 UUID4 then you have 50% chance of generating a collision ([see wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions)). But this number is huge, so we rarely care about it. This is of course under the assumption that the underlying random generator is good enough.

However if you shorten UUID, then you substantially increase that probability. For UUID of length 4 bytes (lets call it SHORTUUID) you have 16^4 combinations which implies (due to [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)) that after generating ~65k such SHORTUUIDs you will have over 50% probability of collision ([see this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/339125/acceptable-to-rely-on-random-ints-being-unique) and note that 4 byte UUID is the same as 32 bit integer). That number is low, like pathetically low. And in reality it gets worse, since not entire UUID4 is random.

So if you care about collisions then don't do that.

If you want to shorten UUIDs then I advice using base64 encoding instead of hex.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm curious, is there any way to guarantee complete uniqueness without having a ridiculously long hash value? Or is this limited by current cryptographic techniques?

Comment: @Seankala the uniqueness can be guaranteed when there's a judge. Meaning a centralized system which can verify it. Like a database. It can also be somewhat guaranteed in a distributed environment with some consensus protocols like Paxos. Here "somewhat" means that the system in consistent but sometimes may fail to generate id. Plus its hard. But for isolated machines there is no way to do that, regardless of the length. It's not a limitation of techniques, it's just how the world works. But UUID with its 128 bits is good enough, you don't have to worry about it, others don't.